# Order Filtered Queryset Count in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a kind of ranking: there are 'students' and there are transactions of items. And if the item is a beer, it counts towards the `beer_list`.

I wrote this manually but this isn't sorted:

```
beer_list = {}
for transaction in Transactions.objects.all():
    if transaction.item.beer:
        if transaction.student.student_ID in beer_list:
            beer_list[transaction.student.student_ID]['beer_count'] += transaction.item_count
        else:
            beer_list[transaction.student.student_ID] = {
                'nickname': (transaction.student.nickname if transaction.student.nickname else 'Anon'),
                'beer_count': transaction.item_count
            }
```

I tried sorting it with `beer_list = sorted(beer_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])` but this throws an error, that this comparison isn't usable with dict to dict usage.

Is there a simple solution for this? I am thinking of something like `Transactions.objects.filter(item.beer=True)` and then using this filtered list to count the objects possibly with an annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each value of the `beer_list` dict is a dict and you want to sort the items of `beer_list` by the `beer_count` key of the sub-dicts, you should make the key function return the value of `beer_count` key of each sub-dict instead:

```
beer_list = sorted(beer_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['beer_count'])
```